Android Firebase Sign In with Pre-Built UI - Email Link Authentication
I'm using the Android Firebase Sign In with Pre-Built UI and trying to get the Email Link Authentication to work.
I can successfully open the Android App in the Main Activity if I hardcode the email.
     auth.signInWithEmailLink(email ?: "", emailLink)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {}

The documentation states this email must be saved however unsure of where to save this email with the Pre-Built UI. There doesn't seem to be a completion listener to intercept the email just before it is sent to the user.


Documentation states this email must be saved however unsure of where to save this email with the Pre-Built UI.

It's up to you to decide the place where to save the email address of the user. I would recommend you save it either in Firestore or in the Firebase Realtime Database.

There doesn't seem to be a completion listener to intercept the email just before it is sent to the user.

When the sign-in with the email link is successful, meaning that the authentication process is complete without any error, then you should save the email address in a database of your choice.
So please make sure to always check what happens if the task is not successful.

When the sign-in with the email link is successful, meaning that the authentication process is complete without any error, then you should save the email address in a database of your choice.  Do you have a code snippet to indicate when this has been successful in the pre-built UI? - this is what I'm after

Add al the logic you want inside the onComplete() function.

Here's the example from Firebase - https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/37986b3f750b005226ee3d6db6a6e0e23dffd7a7/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/FirebaseUIActivity.kt - unfortunately no code for an onCompleteListener after the email has been successfully sent

Everything is explained in the official documentation. What exactly doesn't work the way you expect? When you call sendSignInLinkToEmail() that callback that you get represents the fact the email has been successfully sent, right?

sendSignInLinkToEmail() is for manual/custom use - I'm using the pre-built UI over here -https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui

I don't see any callback for that when using the Firebase-UI library. If you want to have full control over the authentication process, I recommend you use the code in the official documentation.

So did my answer/comments help? Can I help you with other information?

Thanks - I've asked the question on Github - I may need to register for the activity RequestCodes.WELCOME_BACK_EMAIL_LINK_FLOW in signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(         FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract()     ) {  however unsure on how to register for 2 activities
